# Where are input and dom values stored?

Tags: javascript, html

This is a very basic question but I am not sure how to research it.  Let's say I have an html file with an input field and a javascript file that contains a function to grab the values entered in the the input:

HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='value' onclick='getValue()'>
```

JS File:

```
var val;
function getValue(){
    val = document.getElementById('value').value;
    console.log(val)
}
```

When a user inputs a value, that value is stored in the DOM.  I then grab the value from the DOM and store it in my script file loaded in the browser.

Since this is stored within my script file now.  If I were to reload the page, all the values stored would be reset to their original files.

Is it accurate to say the value taken from the DOM is stored in my loaded javascript file?  Or is that stored someplace else?

Comment: I think it's probably accurate to say that how the values are actually held in memory is implementation specific - all you need to worry about is that the variable will contain the data when you need it.  How each JavaScript engine goes about that is for them to worry about.

Comment: There's a *program* (ie, a script) and a running *instance* of that program. The program itself is usually not modified. Think of it like factories making machines, except the factories churn out the machine almost instantly. The program instance is completely thrown away when you navigate (which leads to many ways of saving parts of it for future, like localStorage or requests sent to a server).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Th input value gets stored in the DOM tree (if you want to know where exactly: see the code, e.g.: of Chrome and Firefox). Th JavaScript code you posted makes a copy of that value. The copy is independent of the value stored in the DOM tree, you can delete the input-element and will still have the copy in JavaScript. So the answer is threefold:

- the value is in the DOM-tree first
- a copy of the input value is in the JavaScript Stack when you copy it **and** in the DOM-tree; at least I know of no one-step way to move it.
- if you delete the DOM element the copy you made in JavaScript stays in JavaScript

That makes it possible for example to run JavaScript and DOM-parsing with two distinct programs. Chrome does it with their V8-machine which you can put into some thin wrap and run it separately. You may call the result "node" if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Saying that it's stored "in [your] script file" is a little misleading, but technically accurate.

Any data for DOM elements is stored within the browser's memory for that tab, which it manages itself. Since your Javascript is just a part of that memory, it is in some way stored there. The actual fiddly bits of how that all works is hidden within the browser, and is probably different between browsers.